# Create bins with unique values in each bin

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to bin numeric column (`var`) in such way that there is approximately the same number of rows in in each bin. My additional requirement is that one (unique) value in that column cannot be assigned to more than exactly one bin. For example if value 1 in column `var` is assigned to bin 1 then it is not allowed to assign value 1 also to bin 2.

I am aware of functions `ntile()` or `percent_rank()`, but I do not see how these could be used for the task at hand.

```
drop table if exists binme;
create table binme (var numeric);

insert into binme values
    (0), (0), (0),
    (1), (1), (1.5), (1.5),
    (2), (2), (2), (2.5),
    (3), (3), (3.5), (4.5),
    (5), (6), (7), (10), (11);

select (var * 100)::int, ntile(5) over(order by var), percent_rank() over(order by var) 
from binme;
```

For my example and 5 bins the required result would be:

```
var ntile required_bin
0   1   1   
0   1   1   
0   1   1   
1   1   1   
1   2   1   Has to be in bin 1
1.5 2   2   
1.5 2   2   
2   2   2   
2   3   2   
2   3   2   Has to be in bin 2
2.5 3   3   
3   3   3   
3   4   3   
3.5 4   3   
4.5 4   4   
5   4   4   
6   5   4   
7   5   4   
10  5   5   
11  5   5
```

I somehow intuitively feel it may be necessary to group by `var` first, get number of rows for each value and use some recursive query to assign bin to original data. It should be possible to figure it out from the following:

```
select 
    var, 
    cnt, 
    sum(cnt) over(order by var) as nrows
from 
    (select var, count(*) cnt from binme group by var) a;
```

Comment: My bad, thank you for pointing it out - thought it would be clear from context that my intention is to bin column named `var`. It is fixed now.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `width_bucket` function ?

Comment: `width_bucket` does something different as far as I can see. It assigns bin based on constant width, right? Or is it possible to get result I need?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5b0e/63/0 check the modified solution, it's exactly as you want it, actually I doubt you can get a better approximation, except maybe when using stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for an approximation (which ensures that the same values are placed in the same bucket), then you could indeed use `width_bucket` as mentioned by [@greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222135/greg), but to balance the number of items per bucket, it has to be applied to the cumulated sum and not to the `var` value itself. Here is a demo ([SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5b0e/42/0), improved solution below):

```
SELECT
   o.var,
   WIDTH_BUCKET(o.cumSum, 1, o.cnt + 1, 5) bucket
FROM
   (SELECT
       b.var,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM binme t) AS cnt,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM binme t WHERE t.var <= b.var) AS cumSum
    FROM
       binme b
    ) o
;
```

The cumulated sum (or cumulated count would be more precise maybe) is at least `1` (min inclusive) and max (exclusive) `cnt + 1`, the 3rd parameter specifies the number of buckets. The first bucket is `1` (not `0`, subtract one for a 0-based bucket number).

**Alternatively** you can take `<` instead of `<=` and set the range to `[0,cnt)`, this is probably the **better solution**: [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5b0e/63/0).